$\int_{2n-1}^{2n+1}\frac{dx}{\ln x}>\frac{1}{\ln n} $ lower bound
So I was reading the solution of an exercise and on step stated that:
$$
\int_{2n-1}^{2n+1}\frac{dx}{\ln x}>\frac{1}{\ln n}
$$
For sufficiently large n. I do not understand why this is true or how do you proof it. I tried solving the integral, without any success, and I also found other lower and upper bounds but I could not get the desired results. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Does the function happen to be concave of convex?

I have a proof but it's not a very good one

Since $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ is decreasing, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{2n-1}^{2n+1} \frac{dx}{\ln x} &\ge \int_{2n-1}^{2n+1} \frac{dx}{\ln (2n + 1) } \\
&= \frac{2}{\ln(2n+1)}. \\
\end{align}
Now, $\frac{2}{\ln(2n+1)} > \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ if and only if we have $\ln(n^2) > \ln(2n+1)$, which is equivalent to $n^2 > 2n+1$.  This inequality holds as long as $n \ge 3$ (assuming that $n$ is a positive integer).

The integral is trivially bounded below by the minimum of the function times the length of the interval, i.e:
$\int_{2n-1}^{2n+1}\frac{dx}{\ln x}\geq\frac{2}{\ln(2n+1)}$
And it is left to show that for large enough $n$ we have $\frac{2}{\ln(2n+1)}>\frac{1}{\ln n}$. This inequality is equivalent to $2\ln(n)>\ln(2n+1)$. The left hand side is $\ln(n^2)$, and so the inequality is clearly true for sufficiently large $n$.

Did you use the conversion formula...like converting the limits from a to b....to....0 to1?? And then obtained the bound?

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I used monotonicity of the integral. If $f\leq g$ on $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f\leq\int_a^b g$. In particular, if $m$ is a minimum of $f$ in $[a,b]$ then the constant function $m$ is a lower bound of $f$, and so $\int_a^b f\geq\int_a^b m=m(b-a)$.

I got it, thanks

You can actually develop a slightly tighter bound.
Note first that
$$\int_{2n-1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{\log(x)}\mathrm dx=\operatorname{li}(2n+1)-\operatorname{li}(2n-1)$$
Where
$$\operatorname{li}(x):=\int_0^x \frac{1}{\log t}\mathrm dt$$
Is the logarithmic integral function. It can be equivalently defined as
$$\operatorname{li}(x)=\operatorname{Ei}(\log x)$$
Where
$$\operatorname{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{\mathrm e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm dt$$
Using Laplace's method you can obtain the asymptotic expansion for $\operatorname{Ei}$:
$$\operatorname{Ei}(x)=\frac{\mathrm e^x}{x}\left(1+\frac{1!}{x^1}+\frac{2!}{x^2}+\cdots+ \frac{k!}{x^k}+\mathrm O(x^{-k-1})\right) \\ \text{as}~~~x\to\infty\tag{1}$$
And thus
$$\int_{2n-1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{\log(x)}\mathrm dx=\operatorname{li}(2n+1)-\operatorname{li}(2n-1) \\ =\operatorname{Ei}(\log(2n+1))-\operatorname{Ei}(\log(2n-1)) \\ \approx \frac{\exp(\log(2n+1))}{\log(2n+1)}-\frac{\exp(\log(2n-1))}{\log(2n-1)} \\ =\frac{2n+1}{\log(2n+1)}-\frac{2n-1}{\log(2n-1)}$$
Letting
$$f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{\log(2x+1)}-\frac{2x-1}{\log(2x-1)}$$
We can write
$$\int_{2n-1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{\log(t)}\mathrm dt>f(n)$$
Which is a slightly tighter lower bound than $1/\log(n)$. You can of course do even better by including more terms of $(1)$.

I understand why the integral can be approximated by $f(n)$. But why is it larger than $f(n)$? And why is $f(n) > \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$?

Sorry, in retrospect I misused the asymptotic expansion of $\operatorname{Ei}$ as it isn't convergent. Please disregard.

It is curious, though, how this technique generates tight bounds.
